# How can i reach a JSON node dynamically without using eval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, eval

Path variable is unpredictable. Sometimes it is just `a`, sometimes `a/b`, sometimes `a/b/c` etc. I want to reach a node dynamically according to path. The code below behaves what i want but i can consider if there is a better way to do that without `eval` for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/nuonzngv/1/

```
cont = {
    "a" : {
        "b": {
            "c": "d"
        }   
    }
}
path = "a/b/c";
sect = path.split("/");

path = "cont";
$.each(sect, function( index, value ) {
    path = path + "['" + value + "']";
});

console.log(eval(path));
```

### Solution

I found a plugin that has a getPath function in it, for underscore.js:
https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore-contrib/blob/master/docs/underscore.object.selectors.js.md

Comment: Why don't you access `cont` directly in the loop?

Comment: It may be simpler to convert your current structure to a single object with many properties aka flatten, this could be done dynamically.

Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436457/how-flatten-object-literal-properties

If you needed a/b/c to convert to abc you can modify the answer to include each level's parent property name.

Comment: Path is coming from URL

Comment: See this post about finding nested objects by key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key. Lots of ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Looks lodash have a getPath function that do the job. That would be great if underscore.js have similar function? I really dont want to include another library to my project );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you access your `cont` object directly in the loop? If so:

```
var cont = {
    "a" : {
      "b": {
        "c": "d"
      }   
    }
  },
  o = cont,
  path = "a/b/c",
  sect = path.split("/");

path = "cont";
$.each(sect, function(index, value) {
  path = path + "['" + value + "']";
  if (o) o = o[value];
});

console.log(path+'='+o);
```

gives:

```
cont['a']['b']['c']=d
```

An invalid path will return `undefined`.

---

***Edit**: *psibernetic*'s comment suggesting creating a standalone function:

```
function GetByPath(obj, path) {
  var result = obj;
  $.each(path.split("/"), function(index, value) {
    if (typeof result !== 'undefined' && result !== null) {
      result = obj[value];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: function GetByPath(cont, path)
{
     var result = cont;
     $.each(path.split("/"), function(index, value) {
        if(typeof result !=== 'undefined' && result !== null) {
            result = cont[value];
        }
     }
     return result;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetByPath(cont, path)
{
     var result = cont;
     $.each(path.split("/"), function(index, value) {
        if(typeof result !== 'undefined' && result !== null) {
            result = cont[value];
        }
     }
     return result;
}
```